# Where does OpenVPN Connect (Windows) upload files?

Tags: windows, openvpn

After installation of OpenVPN connect on Windows, I get what is shown on this screenshot:

[image: openvpn connect screenshot]

So, there is wording "Upload file", and picture of a cloud.

Does that mean OpenVPN Connects will upload my .ovpn file to some cloud service?

( If that is the case, I would definitely NOT want to use this software - if it is not the case, why use terminology like "upload file" and drawings of clouds, it makes it all the more confusing for me as an end user... )

Answer (score 2):

OpenVPN Connect doesn't "upload" files anywhere, and is a poor choice of word by the developer.

For OpenVPN-based clients, the `.ovpn` profile is saved to a directory within `%UserProfile%`; for OpenVPN Connect, this is:

```
%UserProfile%\%AppData%\OpenVPN Connect\profiles\<13-digit-#>.ovpn
```

Comment: It is not true that all SSL VPN client software are OpenVPN-based. (Compared to other options that exist, the OpenVPN protocol only barely deserves being called "SSL"; it only uses TLS for authentication, not for data, and then only inside its own custom protocol – compared e.g. to AnyConnect which actually uses raw TLS/DTLS for everything.)

Comment: @u1686_grawity I was not aware there were other SSL VPNs not based on OpenVPN and have removed the factually inaccurate info =]

Comment: Most of them are proprietary protocols, but now that I think of it, I *believe* the term originally wasn't about the protocol in itself but about the way it's deployed – i.e. not as an installed VPN client with its own driver, but browser-based (via HTTPS, hence 'SSL'), like how Cisco's VPN product has a web-based frontend for accessing internal web apps (and yeah, Cisco calls that a "SSL VPN") and I think it used to have a Java-based VPN client that ran in-browser back when Java applets still existed...